# Google Dataflow: get job name and start time from the running pipeline itself

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using Google Dataflow with templates: a template is deployed to GCS by the CI server (Continuous Integration), and later a `gcloud dataflow jobs run` command is used to start a batch job from this template. Now, within the pipeline itself I would like to know the start time of this exact pipeline (to use in the names of the output files).

Is this kind of introspection possible in Beam/Dataflow? Is it possible to get the job name and start time of the job **from within the job itself**? (That is, in the code which executes on the VMs by the Dataflow)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It can be done, just a bit tricky in the current implementation of the template feature.

For job id, you can follow this code snippet:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java#L178

In this piece of code, job id got propagated as a side input, but I think it should also be fine if you don't use side input.

For job start time, there are two ways:
1. Parse the job id with pacific standard time. But I agree it's a bit fragile.
2. Get the current time and pass down as a side input. You can follow the link above.

Thanks.

Comment: Nice, I like the side input idea. Thank you! I wonder, if I create a side input using Create transform, and my pipeline executes on multiple workers - will it actually generate a single version of the side input and distribute it between the workers, or will it generate its own version on every worker? For example, if I use Create transform to inject a "current time" (which will be effectively used as a pipeline start time) - will it be same on all workers in the end, or will each worker have its own value?

Comment: It's a single version.